# How to declare a Cursors With different conditions

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, cursor

I have a procedure `EMPHIRESEPCHAN` which is used to fetch the employees list who are hired, seperated and changed their titles based on a particular time frame. The procedure is as follows:

```
PROCEDURE EMPHIRESEPCHAN  ( p_Start in VarChar2, p_End in VarChar2,                                                           
                  p_Hire IN VarChar2, p_Sep IN VarChar2, p_Changed IN VarChar2, p_Condition1 IN VarChar2, p_Condition2 IN VarChar2) 
IS                                  

CURSOR c_emplst ( p_listtype varchar2 ) IS                                                                           
            select e.emp_id, e.name, e.Rank                                                      
            from person.emp e                                                                                                  
            where emp_id in (select distinct(emp_id) from person.promo                                                               
                    where pdate between p_startDate and p_endDate 
                    and dcode in                                                                                               
                        (select adj from support.descr where typ = 'PROMO' and smeaning = p_listtype) ); 

CURSOR c_promolst ( p_emp_id varchar2 ) IS                                                                              
       select pdate                                               
       from person.promo                                                                                                  
       where emp_id = p_emp_id                                                                                                
       order by 2 desc; 

  Begin

  for EmpRec in c_emplst ('HIRE') 
   LOOP                                                                                 
       for PromoRec in c_PromoLst ( EmpRec.emp ) 
        LOOP                                                                   
           if PromoRec.Dcode in ('TEMPORARY','RETURN','APPOINTED' )                

             -- Do all the operation                                                                  
           end if;                                                                                                      
       end loop;                                                                                                        
   end loop; 

end EMPHIRESEPCHAN;
```

I have to modify the procedure to retrieve the employee list based on `p_Condition1` and `p_Condition2` parameters.

- If the `p_Condition1 is not null and p_Condition2 is null`, I have to retrieve the employees who have `Rank = 'Developer'`
- If the `p_Condition1 is null and p_Condition2 is not null` I have to retrieve the employees who have `Rank = 'Tester'`
- If the `p_Condition1 and p_Condition2 is not null` I have to retrieve the employees who have Rank both 'Developer' and 'Tester'.

I read so many posts in various sites and found answers which I was not able to follow.

Based on the posts, I made modifications to the cursor as follows

```
CURSOR c_emplst ( p_listtype varchar2 ) IS
        select e.emp_id, e.name, e.Rank                                                      
        from person.emp e              
        where ( p_Condition1 = null and p_Condition2 = null = and emp_id in (select distinct(emp_id) from person.promo
                where pdate between p_startDate and p_endDate
                and dcode in (select adj from support.descr where typ = 'PROMO' and smeaning = p_listtype) )
    or ( p_Condition1 > null and p_Condition2 = null = and emp_id in (select distinct(emp_id) from person.promo
                where pdate between p_startDate and p_endDate
        and Rank ='Developer'
                and dcode in (select adj from support.descr where typ = 'PROMO' and smeaning = p_listtype) )
    or ( p_Condition1 = null and p_Condition2 > null = and emp_id in (select distinct(emp_id) from person.promo
                where pdate between p_startDate and p_endDate
        and Rank = 'Tester'
                and dcode in (select adj from support.descr where typ = 'PROMO' and smeaning = p_listtype) );
```

However it's not working.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect these conditions are your problem:

```
p_Condition1 = null
```

Nothing is ever equal to NULL. NULL is not even equal to NULL. Instead, use:

```
p_Condition1 IS NULL
```

Comment: I made the modification as you suggested.. Its working. Thank you so much.